# Iphone programming IOS4 - add video to HTML code in JSON wrapper

Tags: iphone, html, json, video, ios4

I am writing an application which is based in HTML and has a JSON wrapper in the app.

After the 4.0.2 update the iphone does not play video files properly anymore.  All the code to play video files is based in HTML but after the update it shows the play button only and I can not click on the video to play it.  The file is located in the application and a .m4v or .mov format.

I have tried using embed and object formats, none work on IOS4.0.2 but work on previous versions.

I have found a way to wrap the video in an img file {< img src...img properties... onclick="this.parentNode.innerHTML = '\x3Cembed src=\'videos ... video properties etc...>}  this takes 2 clicks to play the video.  One click to remove the image and another click to play the video.

I would like to make the video play in 1 click if possible.

If anyone has any tips/tricks on how to make this possible it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [<video> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/element/video) to display video on a web page:

```
<video src="http://www.example.com/somevideo.mp4">Your browser does not support video</video>
```

This is the HTML5 way of showing video.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..

It's code is in web page format (HTML) for each page, it is being displayed from a Java wrapper (JSON) on an iphone.

That format works great and much shorter code for the ipad, unfortunately I get the same issue with IOS4 on the iphone: I see the video box but when I click play nothing happens.